# Keep Getting Route Errors When There Is Existing Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Doing Hartl's Rail's guide and I keep getting these two errors that claim to have no legit routes, when I have clearly established them. These two errors seems to spark multiple other errors, making it confusing where the true problem is. Attached below is the code, thanks in advance for any guidance.

The errors

```
ERROR["test_account_activation", UserMailerTest, 0.215431]
 test_account_activation#UserMailerTest (0.22s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"password_resets", :email=>"michael@example.com", :format=>nil, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
            app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb:3:in `_app_views_user_mailer_account_activation_text_erb___1022002712257862666_70194962626040'
            app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:10:in `account_activation'
            test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:UserMailerTest>'
        app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb:3:in `_app_views_user_mailer_account_activation_text_erb___1022002712257862666_70194962626040'
        app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:10:in `account_activation'
        test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:UserMailerTest>'

ERROR["test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation", UsersSignupTest, 0.484791]
 test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation#UsersSignupTest (0.48s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"password_resets", :email=>"user@example.com", :format=>nil, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
            app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb:3:in `_app_views_user_mailer_account_activation_text_erb___1022002712257862666_70194962626040'
            app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:10:in `account_activation'
            app/models/user.rb:76:in `send_activation_email'
            app/controllers/users_controller.rb:23:in `create'
            test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
            test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
        app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb:3:in `_app_views_user_mailer_account_activation_text_erb___1022002712257862666_70194962626040'
        app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:10:in `account_activation'
        app/models/user.rb:76:in `send_activation_email'
        app/controllers/users_controller.rb:23:in `create'
        test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
        test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
```

My Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'password_resets/new'

  get 'password_resets/edit'

  get 'sessions/new'

  root             'static_pages#home'
  get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
end
```

Account Activation text

```
To reset your password click the link below:

<%= edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token, email: @user.email) %>

This link will expire in two hours.

If you did not request your password to be reset, please ignore this email and
your password will stay as it is.
```

**Update**
After reading the comments and changing my route file to pass the :id, I'm still getting an error.

New routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root             'static_pages#home'
  get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:id, :new, :create, :edit, :update]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing an ID to the edit path:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"password_resets", :email=>"michael@example.com", :format=>nil, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

So your route should probably be:

```
get 'password_resets/edit/:id', to: 'password_resets#edit'
```

And ensure that an actual ID is passed.

### Edit:

Also, if I remember correctly it actually overrides routes if you later reference it. In this situation you've got the `get 'password_resets/edit'` but also:

```
resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
```

So just leave the latter and ensure an ID is passed as a parameter.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Perhaps I formatted it wrong? I updated the question

Comment: You did it wrong in the route. Remove the ID. In the activation page link add id: @user.id

Answer (score 1):

If you checkout the errors it states:

```
missing required keys: [:id]
```

That's the important part. It means your request isn't passing in the parameter `:id`.